# NextJS DynamicServerError Cookies, Header, and nextUrl.searchParams

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, next.js13, react-server-components

I've been building a Blog engine tool for a while now. I got it to work, and everything was perfect. Until I ran `npm run build` and tried to host it in Vercel. It now shows three error messages, with the same error code `DynamicServerError`. Here are the three errors that occur on build:

`Dynamic server usage: Page couldn't be rendered statically because it used 'nextUrl.searchParams'`

`Dynamic server usage: Page couldn't be rendered statically because it used 'cookies'`

`Dynamic server usage: Page couldn't be rendered statically because it used 'headers'`

I've tried everything Google seems to say, including adding `export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'`, but nothing seems to work.

The codebase is open-sourced: https://github.com/incogiscool/atom and the instructions to host it locally is in the README. I would love some help because I've been working on this issue for a few days with no results.

Thanks in advance for any responses!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that derivatives from the request on the server side shouldn't be in a try/catch statement.

Example:

This was my original code.

```
export const GET = async (request: Request) => {
  try {
  const authHeader = request.headers.get("Authorization");

    if (!authHeader) throw new Error("Invalid project key.");

    const [authType, project_key] = authHeader.split(" ");

    if (authType !== "Bearer") throw new Error("Must be bearer token.");
...
```

Change it to this:

```
export const GET = async (request: Request) => {
  const authHeader = request.headers.get("Authorization");

  try {

    if (!authHeader) throw new Error("Invalid project key.");

    const [authType, project_key] = authHeader.split(" ");

    if (authType !== "Bearer") throw new Error("Must be bearer token.");
...
```